# An explanation of the "print >>..." syntax

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
```

Can anyone explain what the ">>" operators do in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It prints to a file-like object, from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html):

> `print` also has an extended form, defined by the second portion of the syntax described above. This form is sometimes referred to as “print chevron.” In this form, the first expression after the `>>` must evaluate to a “file-like” object, specifically an object that has a `write()` method as described above. With this extended form, the subsequent expressions are printed to this file object. If the first expression evaluates to `None`, then `sys.stdout` is used as the file for output.

The advantage of this, as opposed to `sys.stderr.write()` is that `print >>f, ...` automatically appends a newline to the end of your text (adding newlines manually ie. `sys.stderr.write('waiting for a connection\n')` gets annoying).

For reference, the equivalent Python 3 code is:

```
print('waiting for a connection', file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks!
So the statements,
    print >>sys.stdout, 'hello'
and,
    print 'hello'
would be equivalent, yes?